# Using php scripts on my views in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using the Laravel 4 framework, and I am trying to set up the Facebook authentication system.  I have an authentication system I had set up on another site (not using a framework) that used a config.php and process_facebook.php file.  I am trying to implement this config.php file into my views.  So far, I am including the files in a folder called "includes", within my "app" folder.  I am trying to use the following code to implement it:

```
$app = app();
include($app['path.app'].'/includes/config.php');
```

My question is, where in the view do I put this code?  Do I have to use php tags?  (I am using the blad functionality).  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of working an old script into L4 perhaps look to migrate the facebook auth? https://packagist.org/search/?q=facebook%20auth

Comment: Do not put such logic in your views but instead in a controller or another "model-like" class.

Comment: How did you deal with this issue ? Don't forget to say what solution you choose finally or, at least, accept an answer to close the question if you don't need more explanation. This is important to lead the next viewers to the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel is an MVC framework, the purpose is to organise your code and clean your views. So this shouldn't be in your view.

I think the best way should be :

1. Create a `facebook.php` file in the `config` folder wich contains all your facebook configuration (read http://laravel.com/docs/configuration)
2. Create a folder named `services`, `helpers` or `includes` (as you want) and put `process_facebook.php` inside (I bet it contains the methods to deal with facebook API).
3. Add two lines of configuration to include this new folder

Like that :

```
// composer.json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        [...]
        "app/services",
    ]
},

// start/global.php
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    [...]
    app_path().'/services',
));
```

Then, you can use your facebook class or methods all over your app.

Answer (score 0):

The route you are taking to include configuration files is not recommended, but it is possible. Please see information about [Laravel Configuration Files](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration).

You should be able to use the following in your view:

```php
<?php include(app_path().'/includes/config.php'); ?>
```

As it is a configuration file, it would be better to use `require()` instead of `include()`.
In addition, it would also be better to include the file in the necessary controller(s).